# innerHTML how to create new table row at the top

Tags: javascript, html

I got the table below which is generated by data. Further the button adds another row in the table. My question is, how can I modify the code, that the newly created row will appear on top of the table instead at the bottom.

Usually this can be done with `.insertRow(0)` but I want to use `.innerHTML`. Any ideas?

```js
data = [{
    "property": "animal",
    "value": "dog"
  },
  {
    "property": "car",
    "value": "porsche"
  },
  {
    "property": "snacks",
    "value": "chips"
  }
]

var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable")

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var row = `<tr>
      <td>${data[i].property}</td>
      <td>${data[i].value}</td>
    </tr>`

  myTable.innerHTML += row
}

var insertRow = document.getElementById("insertRow")

insertRow.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = `<tr>
       <td>property</td>
       <td>value</td>
    </tr>`
  myTable.innerHTML += row
})
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#myTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
}

#delRow {
  width: auto;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <!-- filled by script -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="insertRow">+ Row</button>
```

Comment: `but I want to use .innerHTML`, why?

Comment: So you can do it with insertRow, why do you want to use innerHtml then? innerHtml is meant to replace the entire html of an element, not for prepending or appending.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy because I want to use 'contenteditable="true"' directly after. Honestly I do not know how to make them editable with insertRow(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally prepending some string to another is done in re-assignment `value = prefix + value`; so in your code changing `myTable.innerHTML += row` to `myTable.tBodies[0].innerHTML = row + myTable.tBodies[0].innerHTML` would do the trick (I've added `tBodies[0]` just to make it more precise and save HTML parser some error fixing).

But in your case if you really need to build HTML from string, [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) should be more appropriate and performant:

```
myTable.tBodies[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', row);
```

```html
<button onclick="
  myTbody.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'afterbegin',
    `<tr>
      <td>AA</td>
      <td>BB</td>
    </tr>`
  );"
>+ First Row</button>
 
<table border="1">
  <tbody id="myTbody">
    <tr>
      <td>CC</td>
      <td>DD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```